# Date picker not appearing in 4.7.23 and Joomla 3.7.5

Tags: profile, joomla, dates

Not sure what's going on here. Inspecting code for a date field show's right markup (I think), but the date picker doesn't appear on profile date fields on frontend. In backend admin view of profiles, the date picker does appear.

The URL to the page is: http://www.cahpi.ca/demodate , and files in question have "Date" in their label.

I'm using a custom template (which is what you'll see at the above URL), but even when I use the default Beez3 template for Joomla, the date picker icon doesn't appear in the date fields.

I have multilingual civiCRM (English/French), but don't see that this would prevent date picker from appearing.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be a misconfiguration on your site which results in javascript files failing to load.
Inspecting the source of http://www.cahpi.ca/demodate shows a list of scripts which should be loading. For example, `<script type="text/javascript" src="/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js?r=YiBsO">` but trying to open that url, http://www.cahpi.ca/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js?r=YiBsO results in a redirect to the homepage.
That's what you need to fix.

Comment: That's interesting -- when I check my Joomla install, under public_html/components/com_civicrm/ .. there isn't a directory called civicrm... I just have elements/ and /views....

I do have a folder called public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components

Answer (score 0):

Are you using AdminTools to generate your .htaccess file in Joomla? If so, try adding an exception in the "direct access including php" section for that url path. Actually, it's a js file, so it shouldn't really need it. However --- if you are using AdminTools, see the documentation suggestions here: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/website-integration/integrating-with-joomla/#admintools -- as it could be related. It's also possible the js conflicts are caused by plugins. Take a look at your system plugins in particular and try disabling any that indicate they load js, then reload the page, and in that way try to identify the conflict source.